# How do I gracefully stop JHS (J HTML Server)

Tags: j

This [guide](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Guides/JHS/Install) explains how to install and start the J html server from Jconsole, but what is the right way to kill it? `C-d` and `C-c` don't work from the console, and `exit` from inside the browser doesn't seem to do anything.

It just seems wrong to do a `kill -9` on it.

Comment: I already answered below, but remember that to execute any function in J, you need to supply an argument. There's no such thing as a "zero argument" function in the language. Thus, `exit` will just print out the definition of the name `exit`, but `exit''` or `exit 0` will execute it (thus shutting down JHS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
exit''
```

in your browser. You should get a confirmation like:

> Your J HTTP Server has exited.

Comment: Truth is, this piece of information is ridiculously hard to find.

Comment: I can't argue with you, the J documentation is not nearly so robust as the implementation. For what it's worth, `exit` (a mnemonic cover name for `2!:55`) is the standard way to exit any J session, regardless of what frontend one is using. With that said, it wouldn't hurt to mention `exit` (again) in the documentation for JHS, particularly since those docs already describe how to *start* the server. (It's also worth mentioning that JSoftware probably expected the most common use case to be leaving JHS running (as a daemon/service) until reboot.)

Comment: I think I found it once in one of the J forums, but forgot and haven't been able to find it since. And thanks @DanBron for pointing out the universality of `exit`, that's handy as well.